# $.ajax method not calling the controller action method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am calling javascript function on `@Html.ActionLink` clicked event. The Javascript function calls the jquery function in which I have written the `$.ajax` method for calling the json controller method. But it is not calling the controller method.......

Here is my code:

**View**

```
@Html.ActionLink("Submit", "AdminEvaluate", "Application", new { onclick = "Show('" + Model.applicationList.ApplicationId + "','statusList')" })|
```

Here, `ApplicationId` is coming from database and `statusList` is Radio Button group name from where I need to find the selected radio button.

**Javascipt and jQuery code**

```
function Show(appId, appStatus) {
    $.fn.gotof(appId,appStatus);
}
```

Getting parameter from view and passing to jQuery function

**jQuery function**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.fn.gotof = function (appId, appStatus) {
        var selectedItem = $("input[name='" + appStatus + "']:checked").val();  
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Application/UpdateApplicantStatus',
            data: { id: appId , status: selectedItem},
            traditional: true,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

**Controller Method**

```
public JsonResult UpdateApplicantStatus(int id, string status){
    return Json("Correct", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I have put break point on controller method but it is not coming at a break point.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: i think ApplicationController should Application

Comment: You should use @Url.Action(...)

Comment: i have used @url.Action also but it is not working

Comment: yes then you need to use Application only

Comment: why to use application only..... i have used in many controllers but i didn't get any problems before ...

Comment: ohh sorry i got it y to use application only....  i have made changes bt still it doesn't solves my problem.....

Comment: Have you any error in your browser's console ? To avoir routing error, please use Razor syntax, like url: '@Url.Action("UpdateApplicantStatus", "Application")'

Comment: I have used this syntax but it's not working.....

Comment: `url: "/Application/UpdateApplicantStatus/id="+appId+"&status="+selectedItem` try like this keep `data: {}` . let me know

Comment: sry still its not working.. @super cool

Comment: serialize data set

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be this sample help you :) let me know

**ajax call with type :**

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '@Url.Action("UpdateApplicantStatus", "Application")',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: { id: appId , status: selectedItem },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function() { alert('Success'); }

            });
```

**controller :**

```
public ActionResult UpdateApplicantStatus(int id, string status){
    return Json(// blah blah blah ...
}
```

This should work else let me know

Comment: wow thanks a lot .. now the control is coming on the controller method thanks a lot.....

Comment: humm glad it helps :) well i guess in ajax call you did'nt mention GET and url is perfect no issue with that . You tried using actionResult or jsonResult ? let me know . if you used jsonresult and you got this worked means type="GET" is the culprit here (ajax call looks for which type to call default is httpget in controller ). Its hard to find these minor bugs . small things costs us more time :)

Comment: But I have used get also and post also ..  but result was the same. the only thing I haven't used is  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",.. charset i haven't used.... what make a difference if we use it or not use it....

Comment: i used it in both action result and json result but it still not going to controller method

Comment: charset UTF-8 is used for browser dependency purpose i.e encoding sort of stuff . Have you tried other than IE .

Answer (score 1):

Your ajax call is wrong.

If your controller method signature is

```
public JsonResult UpdateApplicantStatus(int id, string appStatus)
```

Then you MUST have parameter names matching with your parameters of your ajax call.
So, instead of

```
data: { id: appId , status: selectedItem}
```

Just write

```
data: { id: appId , appStatus: selectedItem}
```

If you have any other problem, just post the error(s) you should have in your browser's console.

Comment: I have changed the name as per your suggestion but still the control is not coming to controller method and there is no error in my browser console

Answer (score 0):

Maybe parameter names of controller function and ajax calling function should match.

you can try this

data: { id: appId , appStatus: selectedItem},

Comment: I have changed the name as you suggested but still there is same problem

Comment: @Ravindra Are you using areas in your application?

Comment: No I am not using any area

Answer (score 0):

Do that way actually 3 mistakes 1 was notify by @Mr Code the type is missing 2nd your parameters not match as your function takes one you send the data in wrong format..

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.fn.gotof = function (appId, appStatus) {
        var selectedItem = $("input[name='" + appStatus + "']:checked").val();  
        $.ajax({
            url: '/ApplicationController/UpdateApplicantStatus',
data:"{'id':'" + appId + "', 'appStatus': '" + selectedItem+ "'}",//here you format is wrong i correct it
            traditional: true,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

sat on this for hours:

```
When using ajax - json in a js.script file:

the url is written with its real path e.g. -  url: '/contoller/Action',


                                $.ajax({
                                   url: '/NextPage/GetSpDropDown',                                      
                                   data: {'segInputVal': segInputVal}, 
                                    cache: false, 
                                    type: "GET",
                                    dataType: "json",
                                    success: function (result) {
                                     if (result.Success) {
                                     var resultArray = result.Result;.....
```

If the script is written in your HTML page then you must use

```
@(Url.Action(Action,controller))

                                   $.ajax({
                       url: "@(Url.Action("GetSpDropDown", "NextPage"))",
                                    data: { 'segInputVal': segInputVal },
                                    cache: false,
                                    type: "GET",
                                    dataType: "json",
                                    success: function (result) {
                                     if (result.Success) {
                                     var resultArray = result.Result;....
```

And dont forget not to include the word controller in your controller name.

I have had SO MUCH help from stackoverflow- hope to pay a little back